# Viruses detected in wubi.exe supplied with Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, malware

I downloaded an ISO ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-i386.iso and sent the wubi.exe for total virus and it was there that detected below:

```
ByteHero Virus.Win32.Part.a 20,150,602
Jiangmin Trojan / Generic.bvycy
```

https://www.virustotal.com/pt/file/3c4417700eb7fd6588c631f54f0bfd31c5cadd0d16c8251c2edabb9f38d70ec9/analysis/

I would like an explanation about it here ..

Comment: Please don't use WUBI any more as it's deprecated.  Have [a look here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) on how to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Different virus scanners differ in what they classify as viruses and what they don't.  This tool scans files with 56 different virus scanners and reports back on whether any of them found any viruses.

In this case the vast majority (54) found nothing to be concerned about while two identified a virus.  It's up to you to decide how much you trust those two particular virus scanners to be accurate and not to display false positives, which can occasionally happen.

You also need to decide whether you want to trust that service (virustotal) itself.

If you look in the second tab it does say that this is a signed file with verified signature, so the tool itself is saying it is a legitimate file from Canonical UK Ltd and has not been tampered with.  So, if you can trust Canonical not to put viruses into files that lends additional weight to this being a false positive on the part of those 2 out of 56 virus scanners.

Comment: Good one!  Upvoted!  **;-)**